# Prove that B is enumerable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that A is an enumerable set and proves that
$$
B= \{a+b; a,b \in A \}
$$
is enumerable.

I would like to find $f$ injective $f:B \rightarrow A \times A $ and use that $A \times A$ is a enumerable set. Any ideas for $f$?

Comment: Don’t you mean inject into $A\times A$ rather than $A$? Why not just use the obvious surjection from $A\times A$ onto $B$?

Comment: Yeah, I already corrected

Comment: Which obvious surjection do you say?

Comment: @user149513: Map $\langle a,b\rangle$ to $a+b$.

Comment: @user149513 Is there any function from $A\times A$ to $B$ that is more obvious than $(a,b) \to a+b$?

Comment: Yea! I was stuck with the tip given in the exercise and ended up forgetting this result. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is to find a surjection $f:A\times A\rightarrow B$.
Clearly, we may define $f$ by $f(a,b)=a+b$, then $f$ is a surjection.
Therefore, $|B|\leq|A\times A|=\omega$.

We have used the following fact:

Proposition: Assume the Axiom of Choice. If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is
an surjection, then there exists an injection $g:B\rightarrow A$
such that $f\circ g=id_{B}$.

Proof: For each $b\in B$, let $A_{b}=\{a\in A\mid f(a)=b\}$, which
is non-empty because $f$ is surjective. Note that $\{A_{b}\mid b\in B\}$
is a family of non-empty sets, indexed by $B$. By the Axiom of Choice,
there exists a map $g:B\rightarrow\cup_{b\in B}A_{b}=A$ such that
$g(b)\in A_{b}$. Let $b\in B$, then $g(b)\in A_{b}\Rightarrow f(g(b))=b$.
Hence, $f\circ g=id_{B}$. Lastly, we go to show that $g$ is injective.
Let $b_{1},b_{2}\in B$. Suppose that $g(b_{1})=g(b_{2})$, then $b_{1}=f(g(b_{1}))=f(g(b_{2}))=b_{2}$.
Hence, $g$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to build an injection without appealing to Axiom of Choice, in case that matters to you.  Since $A$ is in correspondence with the naturals, it admits a well-ordering.  This well-ordering extends to $A \times A$ by lexicographic order.  For each element $y\in B$, the set $\{(a,b) \in A\times A : a+b = y \}$ is non-empty, hence contains a least element with respect to the well-ordering.  Define $f(y)$ to be that least element.

Concretely, we are writing the elements of $A$ as $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ and choosing $f(y) = (a_{k(y)}, y - a_{k(y)})$ where $k(y) := \min \{ i \in \mathbb N : \exists b \in A, a_i + b = y\} $.